# WCF Connected Service for .NET Core with UsernameToken & PasswordDigest

Tags: wcf, .net-core, usernametoken

WCF .Net Framework does not support UsernameToken with PasswordDigest but microsoft provides a sample project to achieve this :

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aszego/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf/

Does [WCF Connected Service for .NET Core](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=erikcai-MSFT.VisualStudioWCFConnectedService) support this natively? A sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: In .net core still you cant add service references from WCF service

Comment: @programtreasures, you can, I've edited my post so that can click on the extension link.

Comment: yes I check that but i am not sure weather it supports natively or not and it is not part of vs as well it is extention what do u think?